# How do I use a class other than a CGAL Point_3 for point set processing?

Tags: c++, boost, cgal, point-clouds, assimp

I have an array of points that have been loaded by an external library, [Assimp](http://www.assimp.org/), in its own `aiVector3D` class (which doesn't have component accessor functions, just public access to the member variables), and I want to process these points using CGAL's *Point Set Processing* library.

As I have 10s of millions of these points (and could one day be billions), I don't want to create a new array of CGAL `Point_3`s if I can help it.

The [documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/index.html#Chapter_Point_Set_Processing) says:

> Users of this package may use other types to represent positions and normals if they implement the corresponding property maps.

Which seems to imply I can achieve what I want by creating a property map that maps `aiVector3D` to `Point_3`, but after reading both CGAL's and Boost's documentation it's not clear to me how I would go about this.

Am I right in thinking this is the way to go? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I believe you are overestimating the cost of copying the points to a vector of cgal points. You could manage with a point property map that converts an aiVector3D into a cgal point on the fly (see boost::function_property_map for an easy way to create such a property map), but I doubt that the savings are worth it.

Comment: Two reasons I want to avoid a simple copy, 1) the input point set could be billions one day and having two copies in memory could cause issues. 2) It just doesn't *seem* elegant. 1) can be mitigated with memory mapped files, and 2) can be put in a drawer and ignored :) I'll try the `boost::function_property_map`, and run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not this is more or less efficient (for some meaning of efficient), here's what I came up with to map `aiVector3D` to `CGAL::Point_3` (using a `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>` kernel), including transformations.

```
template <typename T>
struct AItoP {
    AItoP(const aiScene* scene, const aiNode* node) :
            _scene(scene),
            _node(node),
            _mesh(0)
    {
        _mesh = _scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[0]];
        _xform = _node->mTransformation * _scene->mRootNode->mTransformation;
    }

    T operator()(const size_t& x) const {
        aiVector3t<double> v(_mesh->mVertices[x].x, _mesh->mVertices[x].y, _mesh->mVertices[x].z);
        v *= _xform;

        return T(v.x, v.y, v.z);
    }
private:
    const aiScene* _scene;
    const aiNode* _node;
    const aiMesh* _mesh;
    aiMatrix4x4t<double> _xform;
};
```

...

```
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>

void my_processing_function() {
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices(mesh->mNumVertices);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; ++i){
        indices[i] = i;
    }

    double cell_size = 0.05;
    std::vector<std::size_t>::iterator end;
    end = CGAL::grid_simplify_point_set(indices.begin(),
            indices.end(),
            make_function_property_map<const size_t&, Point, AItoP<Point> >(AItoP<Point>(_scene, node)),
            cell_size);
}
```